# C: How to enable __<Flag_Name>__

Tags: c, macros, flags

I have the following piece of code:

```
#ifdef __SYM_TRACE__
#define SYM_TRACE( L, F )   { SETTRACE_LEVEL(L); tracefunc F; }
#define SYM_TRACE2( F )     { SETTRACE_LEVEL(SYM_MODULE); tracefunc F; }
#else
#define SYM_TRACE( L, F )
#define SYM_TRACE2( F )
#endif
```

Now the issue is that where would I find the **SYM_TRACE** flag and how do I enable it? There is no macro in the code by the name of **SYM_TRACE**, so where is this getting picked from?

Also, another beginner question. Could someone please explain the significance of __ before and after the macro name.

Thanks, 
Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is already there so consider it just as addition

You can do following option to enable `__SYM_TRACE__`

write `#define __SYM_TRACE__` in header file which is getting used with shown piece of code.(Do not forget to guard it with #ifndef endif)

You can add  it in Makefile as suggested by @Ishmeet using `-D__SYM_TRACE__`

Now if you are talking about `_Name_` then it is a way to make difference between standard(or predefined) macros with user defined.For example GCC predefined macros like `__WCHAR_TYPE__` and `__WINT_TYPE_` having underscore before and after.

Answer (score 1):

```
__SYM_TRACE__
```

is probably defined in your make file, and __ is just the name, I dont think that has a significance, maybe it does during porting on other platforms.
Most C compilers accept the option -D to define a symbol:

`gcc -D__SYM_TRACE__ file.c`

Comment: thanks, so if i am looking for a macro, i am looking for __SYM_TRACE__ or just SYM_TRACE?

Comment: that depends on the compiler you are using, for example IAR, Macros are defined under project->options->C/C++ Compiler->Preprocessor->Defined symbols,

Comment: I am using eclispe and makefiles  to build. any idea, where the marcos would be?